# How are security patches applied to the core OpenJDK source?

Tags: java

If I've understood correctly: OpenJDK is the physical source code, hosted in Mercurial.

Parties build and package that, offering a variety of release schedules:
e.g.

- OracleOpenJDK will provide Java 11.0.0, then two *security patches* 11.0.1 and 11.0.2
- AdoptOpenJDK will provide Java 11 builds for 4 years, but will rely on other parties pushing *security patches* back into OpenJDK
- RedHat will provide a (commercial) build as part of RHEL, BUT will push *security patches* back to the OpenJDK source

So I'm confused.

Is each party just fixing the same security issues in their own forks?
That seems mad.

Why aren't security patches done on the core OpenJDK source? Then everyone gets them.

And, finally, are Oracle planning to push their security patches back to the core OpenJDK source?  If so, why would anyone use OracleOpenJDK, when AdoptOpenJDK will be exactly the same code, and provided for 4 years?

Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by "OracleOpenJDK"?  Do you mean OpenJDK as produced by the OpenJDK project?   Please provide a reference that explains your terminology.

Comment: @StephenC I specifically mean "OpenJDK builds from Oracle": http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html

Comment: OK ... so could you put that into the question?   And a reference to the "2 security patches" information?